# How to Post date to server on AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-ec2

express-mongodb` backend deployed on a Linux server on ASW EC2,  when I test the backend on personal pc, I use

```
http://localhost:3000/app_v1/api/users
```

with body:

```
{
    "user_name" : "josh",
    "user_email" : "josh.M@gmail.com",
    "user_password" : "123"
}
```

to register a user and it works well.

Now I have deployed it on AWS EC2 (Ubantu 16.04), and want to do the same thing. I have launched the MongoDB and node server which shows the server started on port 3000.

Trying to post the data to server by postman, but it shows there is an error when connecting to

```
http://ec2-18-216-132-220.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/app_v1/api/users

with body:

{
    "user_name" : "josh",
    "user_email" : "josh.M@gmail.com",
    "user_password" : "123"
}
```

postman message:

```
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out, that my server listens to 3000 and I didn't allow it in my security group, add the 3000 in inbound and it works.